# Resetting score on snake game

Tags: javascript

This is my javascript code below. I get to reset the game with the button, but the score wont reset. What am i missing?

```
function resetScore() {
  console.log("reset");
  score = 0;
}

let score = 0;
    
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.onclick = function() {
  snake = [
    {x: 200, y: 200},
    {x: 190, y: 200},
    {x: 180, y: 200},
    {x: 170, y: 200},
    {x: 160, y: 200}
  ];
  main()
  resetScore()
}
    
score += 50;
    
(document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score);
```

Comment: your code looks like it probably functions correctly, but you may not be displaying the new score after calling `resetScore`. are you doing `document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score` right after resetting the score?

Comment: Yeah my document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score is after the reset but it keeps displaying the score from the last round.

Comment: you might need to provide more code then, as this issue is likely not with the code you've provided so far.

Comment: I see. thank you. Do you have any tips to what code i can add?

Answer (score -1):

You are not updating the score properly on your score HTML tag. Try instead

```
function resetScore() {
  console.log("reset");
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 0;
}
```

```js
function main() {
  console.log("main");
}


function resetScore() {
  console.log("reset");
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 0;
}

let score = 0;

var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.onclick = function() {
  snake = [{
      x: 200,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 190,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 180,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 170,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 160,
      y: 200
    }
  ];
  main()
  resetScore()
}

score += 50;

(document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score);
```

```html
<body class="container">
  <p id='score'></p>
  <button id="button">Reset</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to `innerHTML` the score with every reset:

```
function resetScore() {
  console.log("reset");
  score = 0;
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
}

let score = 0;
let button = document.getElementById("button");

button.onclick = function() {
  snake = [
    {x: 200, y: 200},
    {x: 190, y: 200},
    {x: 180, y: 200},
    {x: 170, y: 200},
    {x: 160, y: 200}
  ];
  main();
  resetScore();
}
    
score += 50;
    
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
```

Comment: the code works for resetting the score! but it also still continues the score from the last run

Comment: then it would be a good idea to post more of your code...